# Is it possible to build a VS 2010 solution using TFS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild, biztalk-2010

I have a TFS 2012 configuration, and the majority of my assets are based on C# in VS 2012 solutions. Right now I'm trying to integrate some other assets into my build, however these are BizTalk 2010 assets in a VS 2010 solution.

BizTalk 2010 is explicitly not supported in VS 2012; instead, VS 2012 supports only BizTalk 2013. My challenge is to build this VS 2010 solution in our TFS 2012 environment, alongside our VS2012 solution, since upgrading to BizTalk 2013 is not an option.

I tried naively to add the VS 2010 solution to the build definition, but the compiler barfs on my btproj files, probably because it's treating them as if they were BizTalk 2013.

```
CSC (0): Source file 'C:\Builds\1005\TeamProject\Sources\Source\BizTalk\BizTalk.Schemas\SchemaHelper.xsd.cs' could not be found
```

For what it's worth, there is no evidence that my BizTalk 2010 project references this .xsd.cs file; I'm assuming this is a sidecar file introduced with BizTalk 2013 that the compiler is expecting to find. My build server has both VS 2010 and VS 2012 installed.

Has this kind of thing come up before? I can't seem to find much information. My first instinct is to attempt to add a copy of the "Items to Build" field in the build process parameters that will be used explicitly for VS2010 solutions, and then attempt to define an activity to invoke the 2010 compiler against those projects.

Does this sound sane? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can likely get it to work in the 2012 build server by forcing the build through 2010 I believe that the only result of trying to build Biztalk 2010 is pain and suffering. Notwithstanding 2012.

You can create a purely 2010 build server and environment and plug that into TFS 2012: http://nakedalm.com/visual-studio-2012-update-2-supports-2010-build-servers/

Comment: Interesting idea. Does that preclude building our assets based in VS2012? Getting these two things under the same build is the principle issue for us.

Comment: This ended up being a decent amount of effort, but it did succeed. We were able to configure a build server as both a TFS2010 Build Controller and TFS2010 Build Agent, while also installing the build assets for BizTalk 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 for our other assets.

Comment: You should be able to do the opposite as well... push your VS2010 and BizTalk 2010 builds through Team Foundation Build 2012... however I think that what you did do was an easer path...